# What is the simplest way to do a RegExp for variations on a pattern?

Tags: javascript, regex, function

My code (below) searches a string for the 4 possible variations on a pattern that the string may contain `dd[Q]dd[A], d[Q]d[A], dd[Z]dd[A], d[Z]d[A]`. My goal is to always find the number between character Q and A (or Z and A) and return the number and index position.

I believe my code could be written in a much more efficient manner, but I'm not sure what it would be (I'm a beginner coder). Any thoughts?

```js
{
var str = 'TY 111-222 4Q8A';
var result;
var index;
/*RegExp the 4 possible variations of the pattern*/
var srchAlpha = /\d\d\*?[Q]\d\d\*?[A]/i; 
var srchBeta = /\d\*?[Q]\d\*?[A]/i; 
var srchGamma = /\d\d\*?[Z]\d\d\*?[A]/i;
var srchDelta = /\d\*?[Z]\d\*?[A]/i;
/*Index the 4 possible variations of the pattern*/
var indexAlpha = str.search(srchAlpha);
var indexBeta = str.search(srchBeta);
var indexGamma = str.search(srchGamma);
var indexDelta = str.search(srchDelta);
/*Determine which variation of the pattern the string contains*/
if (indexAlpha != -1) {
result = str.slice(indexAlpha+3, indexAlpha+5);
index = indexAlpha+3;
} else if (indexBeta != -1) {
result = str.slice(indexBeta+2, indexBeta+3);
index = indexBeta+2;
} else if (indexGamma != -1) {
result = str.slice(indexGamma+3, indexGamma+5);
index = indexGamma+3;
} else if (indexDelta != -1) {
result = str.slice(indexDelta+2, indexDelta+3);
index = indexDelta+2;
} else {
result = "";
index = "";
}
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
document.getElementById("index").innerHTML = index;
}
```

```html
<p>result: <span id="result"></span></p>
<p>index: <span id="index"></span></p>
```

Comment: Just try `[QZ](\d+)A`

Comment: And you can get the index by using `/[QZ](\d+)A/.exec(str).index`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there might be no digits between the letters, then, I believe, `[QZ](\d*)A` will do.

Make it `[QZ](\d+)A` if at least one digit is expected.

If there will be one or two digits, use `[QZ](\d{1,2})A`.

Do the following to extract the digit(s) and index(es):

```
const regex = /[QZ](\d+)A/;
const input = "TY 111-222 4Q8A";

const match = input.match(regex);

if (!match)
  // no match

const digits = match[1];
const digitsIndexes = input.indexOf(digits);
```

---

For two groups of digits (before and after the `Q` or `Z` character) use two capturing groups:

```
const regex = /(\d+)[QZ](\d+)A/;

// ...

const digitGroups = [ match[1], match[2] ];
const digitGroupsIndexes = digitGroups.map(group => input.indexOf(group));
```

Comment: Thanks! `/(\d*)[QZ](\d{1,2})A/i` works from your suggestion. For some reason, your suggestion for match/index doesn't work (I get undefined for match and index -1).

Comment: That's because adding another capturing group shifted their indexes in regex match array. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: That makes sense. Do I need to wrap the code in a function? I'm getting a "unexpected token const" error in the console.

Comment: Replacing the comment with the line of actual code will make it work

Comment: I have `if (!match)` in that section. That won't work now?

Comment: That is not relevant to the original question. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else for details

Answer (score 0):

For reference, based on Dmitry Parzhitsky's answer, I have the full answer here.

```js
{
var regex = /(\d+)[QZ](\d+)A/;
var input = "TY 111-222 4Q8A";
var match = input.match(regex);

if (!match) {
digits = "";
digitsIndexes = "";
} else {
var digits = match[2];
var digitsIndexes = input.indexOf(digits);
}
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = digits;
document.getElementById("index").innerHTML = digitsIndexes;
}
```

```html
<p>result: <span id="result"></span></p>
<p>index: <span id="index"></span></p>
```